# Unable to load 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' from dnx using RC1 of the coreclr runtime

Tags: .net, dnx, coreclr

Not sure if I should expect this to work or not, but I'm trying to use a .net library (https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api) from a simple console application using coreclr RC1 on my mac and I'm hitting the following runtime exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddd0da4d3e678217' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddd0da4d3e678217' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
File name: 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations'
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at Hl7.Fhir.Introspection.ModelInspector.Import(Assembly assembly)
   ...
```

Here is the relevant portion of my project.json:

  `"dependencies": {
    "Hl7.Fhir.DSTU21": "0.90.4"
  },
  "commands": {
    "ConsoleApplication": "ConsoleApplication"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }`

I tried adding `"System.ComponentModel": "4.0.1-beta-23516"` to the dnxcore50 dependencies but it didn't seem to do anything.
What is strange is that when I change from the coreclr runtime to the mono runtime (via dnvm), everything works properly. Is this expected to work with the coreclr or should I be looking somewhere else for what is/isn't supported there yet?

I am new to .NET and so I might be doing something dumb...

Comment: Have you tried pulling the "System.ComponentModel.Annotations" package (not just "System.ComponentModel") ?

Comment: The latest version of `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` published on NuGet is `4.0.11-beta-23516`. You should examine `project.lock.json` to see *which component* try to load `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` in such strange version. Alternatively you can use `dnu list --filter System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations --details` to locale the component, which loads DataAnnotations

Comment: By the way, the latest version of `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` (not the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`) on the "Night build" NuGet repository https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2/ is `4.1.0-rc2-23623`. The NuGet repository https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/ have version `4.1.0-rc2-23706`. There are exist `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations` in version `6.0.0-rc2-16833` on aspnetcidev and in version `6.0.0-rc1-final` on main NuGet repository. It seems that you have problem with `Hl7.Fhir.DSTU21` which is old. You should remove `"dnxcore50"` part and use only `dnx451`

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I tried adding System.ComponentModel.Annotations but still no luck.  I'm using the dnx/coreclr RC1 from my Mac and so I don't think I can run with just dnx451.

Comment: dnx451 on Mac/Linux entails Mono

Comment: OK.  As I mentioned in the question this exact setup is working great if I switch to the mono runtime. The problem I mention is specific to coreclr.